# jQuery: Check form's parent div'sclass on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a HTML mark up like this.

```
 <div class="formSection custom">
   <form id="support">
   </form>
 <div>
```

The class name "custom" to the div is added dynamically and I need to check in on form submission.

So far I have this and its not working.

```
 $('#support').on('submit', function(e) {
       if ($(".support").parent().hasClass("custom")) {
           alert("Yeah, It does have class");
       }
 }
```

It works when I do

```
if ($(".formSection").hasClass("custom"))
```

I don't want my jquery to be so rigid. I want to track down form's parent and check its class. Is there a way I can do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

firstly, you are calling

```
if ($('.support'))
```

indicating you are searching for an element with a **class** of `.support`, but your `<form>` has an **id** of `#support`

probably the best way to do it would be - notice the use of `$(this)`

```
$('#support').on('submit', function(e) {
    if ($(this).parent().hasClass('custom')) {
        alert('Yeah, It does have class');
    }
}
```